# Email link to a local file (e.g. file://User/...)

Tags: macos, finder, url

This has been asked before, but the only solution I've seen requires the recipient to install some software (e.g. lincastor), which doesn't work for me. Any better ideas?

Comment: Can you add links to the previous question(s) which didn't help you? This might avoid others giving you the same answers again.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You need three slashes.
2. It needs to be a complete filepath from root, and can't use `~`

So something like `file:///Users/username/Desktop/qwe.txt`

3. Mail does not have permission to open local links. It's possible that the recipient may be able to fix this by adding the application to "Full Disk Access" list in System Preferences > Security & Privacy. Otherwise, the recipient will have to copy the filepath and paste it somewhere where they can use it.

Comment: Thanks. This got me a few steps further I think, but I'm not getting the "no associated application found" error when trying to open the link...